# Fill dataframe rows according to the arrangement of the headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ordereddictionary

I need to create a dataframe where each value in each row is appended to the related headers. The rows are saved as `OrderedDict` items. This is complicated because some `key : value` dictionary pairs do not have a valid key (it's nan). I want to skip over these null items.

Data looks like this:
`{'Exercise_Name': 'Barbell Behind Neck Press', 'Utility': 'Basic', 'Mechanics': 'Compound', 'Force': 'Push', 'Deltoid, Anterior': 'Target_1', nan: 'Antagonist Stabilisers_15', nan: 'Target_7', nan: 'Target_8', nan: 'Target_9', 'Deltoid, Lateral': 'Synergists_1', 'Supraspinatus': 'Synergists_2', 'Triceps Brachii': 'Synergists_3', 'Trapezius, Middle': 'Synergists_4', 'Trapezius, Lower': 'Synergists_5', 'Serratus Anterior, Inferior Digitations': 'Synergists_6', 'Dynamic Stabilizers': 'Synergists_7', 'Triceps, Long Head': 'Synergists_8', nan: 'Synergists_28', nan: 'Synergists_29', 'Trapezius, Upper': 'Stabilisers_1', 'Levator Scapulae': 'Stabilisers_2', nan: 'Stabilisers_22', nan: 'Stabilisers_23',`

I have multiple rows of this data (i.e. multiple exercises) that need to be appended to this dataframe. Each exercise will have a different `key` saved as `nan` (i.e. `null`) that needs skipping.

Comment: For anyone reading this, I ended up doing this
1. Reading my dataframe line by line into a series. Converting this into a dict.
2. Swapping the key:value pairs of SOME of the dict pairs (I didn't need to swap all). 
3. Appending this new dict to the respective columns, by iterating through the columns. For any KeyErrors I inputted np.nan (i.e. nonetype)

Answer (score -1):

can you say nan = 'nan' and proceed your program. Then you can simply get rid of 'nan' k,v pairs.

Regards.

```
nan = 'nan'
```

b = {'Exercise_Name': 'Barbell Behind Neck Press', nan : 'ccc'}

print(b)

{'Exercise_Name': 'Barbell Behind Neck Press', 'nan': 'ccc'}

Comment: Are you saying to convert nan into a string, then remove all values with that key from the dictionary? How would I the ensure the rest of the data is appended to the correct columns, as nan current ensures every row is the same length

Comment: basically yes, because I am having a name error with the format you shared. 
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined

Comment: Thanks, but I then run into the problem of creating uneven length rows in the dataframe. the nan values are basically filler text that ensures the rows are the correct length.

Comment: OK, I thought that you try to get rid of nan values. However, if you need your data in a dictionary format, you will still get "name 'nan' is not defined" errors if nan is not defined.
I think it might be a workaround for you, you can even get len of the nan (in which converted 'nan') as following: 

nan = 'nan'


b = {'Exercise_Name': 'Barbell Behind Neck Press', nan : 'cccdd'}


print(len(b[nan]))

output:

5